# Get a list of files in a folder without changing directory

Tags: python

I have a following problem. My .py script is saved in `"C:\Users\vojtam\Desktop\my_script"`. I would like to get a list of all files that are saved in `"C:\Users\vojtam\Desktop\my_folder"`. I know that I can use:

```
os.chdir("C:\Users\vojtam\Desktop\my_folder")
list_of_files = os.listdir()
```

But is it possible without the command `os.chdir`? Thanks a lot!

Comment: `os.listdir("C:\Users\vojtam\Desktop\my_folder")`

Comment: Yes, os.listdir() accepts a param, path.  you can give absolute path.

Answer (score 2):

`help` is often helpful in such case, if you do in `python` terminal `help(os.listdir)` it will inform you

```
listdir(path=None)
    Return a list containing the names of the files in the directory.

    path can be specified as either str, bytes, or a path-like object.  If path is bytes,
      the filenames returned will also be bytes; in all other circumstances
      the filenames returned will be str.
    If path is None, uses the path='.'.
```

and so on, therfore in this case just do

```
import os
list_of_files = os.listdir("C:\Users\vojtam\Desktop\my_folder")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `glob`:

```
import glob

list_of_files = glob.glob("C:\Users\vojtam\Desktop\my_folder\*")
```